# Achieve personalization on AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

How can I achieve personalization on AMP pages? 
e.g., how to render recommended items (based on personalized content), buyers who bought X also bought Y.

Answer (score 3):

We have two options to achieve personalization on AMP :

1. For small parts of the page, consider using amp-list which is often the best solution. This component makes a call to the server at load time for data to slot into a template. Since this is a call made on load, this is not ideal for large parts of the page, but recommended items are the classic use case for this. 
   Please read [amp-list documentation](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-list/), and [credential parameter](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list#credentials-(optional)) for more details.
2. For more deeply personalized content such as the number of items in a cart, shopping cart, "recommended for you", commenting, "like"ing etc, you could combine with amp-access to have a notion of authentication. Please check [amp-access](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-access/) component for more details.

AMP By Example's [product page sample](https://ampbyexample.com/samples_templates/product_page/preview/) contains a related products section using amp-list.
Here is a link to the [source](https://github.com/ampproject/amp-by-example/blob/57036e9ee3ecca191738a683e254311ee0c9c3e9/src/50_Samples_%2526_Templates/Product_Page.html#L709-L757).

Furthermore, to render product list related to user’s past purchases,  CLIENT_ID parameter implementation and a careful reading of the [Managing non-authenticated user state with AMP document](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-managing-user-state.md) should help.

Comment: Also, take a look at https://ampbyexample.com/introduction/amp_for_e-commerce_getting_started/#display-personalized-content which summarizes approaches for personalized data